# how can we clear complete browser cookies by JavaScript or react?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie, cookie-httponly, react-cookie

When I work on my local setup or on server, I run into a cookie issue because I have to manually clear browser cookies before seeing new changes. I'm using react for my application.

By Javascript document.cookie I'm not able to access that cookies so can’t delete it.

I need to clear by code so the user can see latest changes at all times. Hard refresh will solve the problem, but that's not a good idea.

I tried unregistering the serviceworker by using serviceworker.unregister(), but it didn't work.

Note: My project will run only from the server, no cookies or cache will be needed.

If anyone has same issue or any suggestion please provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is a JavaScript library. It can't do anything that JavaScript you write yourself can't do.

`document.cookie` is the API provided for editing cookies from client-side JavaScript. If the cookie you want to edit does not appear there (typically because it is marked `httpOnly` or belongs to a different domain) then you can't access it with client-side JS.

You'll need to find an approach to this which doesn't involve client-side JS.

---

> Hard refresh will solve the problem, but that's not a good idea.

This makes it sound like your real problem is [caching](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) and whatever you to do delete cookies manually is also deleting  your cache for that website. You should adjust your cache headers in development instead of worrying about cookies.